# How do I completely quit Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In order for Outlook 2007 to work with my VPN, I must connect to the VPN before running Outlook.

However, if Outlook is already launched, I can't just quit Outlook before connecting to the VPN, because I can't quit the OUTLOOK.EXE background process. Now, I can terminate the process with Task Manager, but that seems like kind of a brute force solution.

Is there another, better way to get Outlook to quit fully before I connect to my VPN?

Answer (score 4):

If you do File/Exit rather than clicking the Close button, it does a "proper" quit.  It can take a couple of minutes to fully close down this way.

But still, this is Outlook, so it may get stuck even so.  In which case you'll need to Task Manager quit it.